# How to design relation between tables employee,client and phone Number?

Tags: sql, database

I have a relational database with a `Client` table, containing `id`, `name`, and `address`, with many phone numbers 
and I have an `Employee` table, also containing `id`, `name`, `address`, etc., and also with many phone numbers.

Is it more logical to create one "Phone Number" table and link the Clients and Employees, or to create two separate "Phone Number" tables, one for Clients and one for Employees?

If I choose to create one table, can I use one foreign key for both the Client and Employee or do I have to make two foreign keys?

If I choose to make one foreign key, will I have to make the Client `id`s start at 1 and increment by 5, and Employee `id`s start at 2 and increment by 5 so the two `id`s will not be the same?

If I create two foreign keys will one have a value and the other allow nulls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution which I would go with would be:

```
CREATE TABLE Employees (
    employee_id    INT            NOT NULL,
    first_name     VARCHAR(30)    NOT NULL,
    ...
    CONSTRAINT PK_Employees PRIMARY KEY (employee_id)
)

CREATE TABLE Customers (
    customer_id    INT            NOT NULL,
    customer_name  VARCHAR(50)    NOT NULL,
    ...
    CONSTRAINT PK_Customers PRIMARY KEY (customer_id)
)

-- This is basic, only supports U.S. numbers, and would need to be changed to
-- support international phone numbers
CREATE TABLE Phone_Numbers (
    phone_number_id    INT            NOT NULL,
    area_code          CHAR(3)        NOT NULL,
    prefix             CHAR(3)        NOT NULL,
    line_number        CHAR(4)        NOT NULL,
    extension          VARCHAR(10)    NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_Phone_Numbers PRIMARY KEY (phone_number_id),
    CONSTRAINT UI_Phone_Numbers UNIQUE (area_code, prefix, line_number, extension)
)

CREATE TABLE Employee_Phone_Numbers (
    employee_id        INT    NOT NULL,
    phone_number_id    INT    NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_Employee_Phone_Numbers PRIMARY KEY (employee_id, phone_number_id)
)

CREATE TABLE Customer_Phone_Numbers (
    customer_id        INT    NOT NULL,
    phone_number_id    INT    NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_Customer_Phone_Numbers PRIMARY KEY (customer_id, phone_number_id)
)
```

Of course, the model might changed based on a lot of different things. Can an employee also be a customer? If two employees share a phone number how will you handle it on the front end when the phone number for one employee is changed? Will it change the number for the other employee as well? Warn the user and ask what they want to do?

Those last few questions don't necessarily affect how the data is ultimately modeled, but will certainly affect how the front-end is coded and what kind of stored procedures you might need to support it.

Comment: I think this makes updates more complicated than they need be e.g. must have the ability to 'split' (e.g. two clients who previously shared a phone number now have separate numbers), 'merge' (e.g. two clients who previously had separate numbers now share a phone number), deleting 'orphaned' phone numbers, etc. Sometime it is worth the effort but for phone numbers I suspect not. Usually it is a field read by a human allowing them to contact a contactable entity by telephonic means e.g. `VARCHAR(35)` with perhaps a `CHECK` allowing only digits plus a few other characters. K.I.S.S. ;)

Comment: It's only complicated if you need it to be. Remove the unique index in the phone numbers table if you don't want to have to worry about splits and merges, but that's a conscious decision that you will have to remember that when you change my home phone number you'll also have to change my wife's home phone number seperately. That's fine as long as the business rules call for that and as long as all parties are aware of the limitations and advantages of each method.

Comment: My point: remove the unique index and there's not much point in having the table at all. "when you change my home phone number you'll also have to change my wife's home phone number seperately[sic]"... yes, that's another issue: you if you assume that people with the same `phone_number_id` share a phone but what if one was a typo and when it gets corrected by the person then *both* get changed and now the other one is wrong and so it goes on... my point again: telephone numbers are not usually entities in their own right so don't usually need a separate table.

Answer (score 1):

"The Right Way", allowing you to use foreign keys for everything, would be to have a fourth table phoneNumberOwner(id) and have fields client.phoneNumberOwnerId and employee.phoneNumberOwnerId; thus, each client and each employee has its own record in the phoneNumberOwner table. Then, your phoneNumbers table becomes (phoneNumberOwnerId, phoneNumber), allowing you to attach multiple phone numbers to each phoneNumberOwner record.

Comment: The downside is that this approach adds complexity to the schema. You might be better off by having phoneNumbers(type, ownerId, phoneNumber), with type being 'client' or 'employee' and handling that logic in your application outside of the database. This excludes the possibility of a foreign key between phoneNumbers.ownerId and client.id/employee.id.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can somehow justify it, but to my way of thinking it is not logical to have employees and clients in the same table. It seems you wan to do this only so that your foreign keys (in the telephone-number table) all point to the same table. This is not a good reason for combining employees and clients.

Use three tables: employees, clients, and telephone-number. In the telephone table, you can have a field that indicates employee or client. As an aside, I don't see why telephone number needs to be a foreign key: that only adds complexity with very little benefit, imo.

Comment: +1 This is how I would do it, only I wouldn't call the table `telephone-number`, because the `-` would need to be escaped...

Answer (score 0):

Unless there are special business requirements I would expect a telephone number to be an attribute of an employee or client entity and not an entity in its own right.

If it were considered an entity in its own right it would be 'all key' i.e. its identifier is the compound of its attributes and has no attributes other than its identifier. If the sub-attributes aren't stored apart then it only has one attribute i.e. the telephone number itself! Therefore, it isn't usually 'interesting' enough to be an entity in its own right and a telephone numbers table, whether superclass or subclass, is usually overkill (as I say, barring special business requirements).